# How to apply "for each" loop coverage testing?

Tags: loops, testing, foreach, code-coverage, test-coverage

I was wondering if "for" loop coverage can be applied to "for each" loops as well.. If so, how can it be done on the following code sample?

```
1. public static void foreachDisplay(int[] data){
  2. System.out.println("Display an array using for 
  3. each loop");
  4. for (int a  : data) {
    5. System.out.print(a+ " ");
    6. }
  7. }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is special about this that makes it difficult?

Comment: Why don't you show how easy it is to be tested using the for loop coverage and share your knowledge? :)

Comment: I don't know enough about what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to get line 5 to show up as being covered?

Comment: I need to write test cases that covers the testing possibilities of this "for each" loop and I know how to do it if it was a normal "for" loop but can't imagine it in this case.

Comment: How would you do it for a normal for loop?

Comment: I will apply the loop coverage by selecting values that will cause the loop to run once or twice and I may test the function response to boundary values for ex.

Comment: or maybe if the loop ends at n, I will try to enter a value that will cause n-1,n or n+1 iterations

Comment: If you want the loop to run once, you can provide a data array with one element.

Comment: Aha ok so since I don't know the exact number of list inputs, I will have to assume a value and work based on it.. I guess I got it ^_^' thank you so much :)

Comment: This hint was really useful

Comment: What exactly are you testing??? The compiler?

Answer (score 0):

You should test this at least twice, once with an empty array and the second with a few elements in the array.  You could also test it with exactly 1 element in the array, if you want to count that as the boundary value.